# Java. Доступ к полю родительского класса из метода внутреннего класса

Tags: java

Вопрос не несет практической значимости, но очень интересен в плане понимания языка.

```
public class A {
    private class B {}
    private String myFinalNameField;

    private B b = new B() {
        private void myMethod(String myFinalNameFields) {
            [???]myFinalNameFields = myFinalNameFields;
        }
    };
}
```

Как присвоить полю `myFinalNameField` класса **А** значение параметра `myFinalNameFields` метода `myMethod` класса **B** ? Скорее всего я неверно сформулировал вопрос, это можно сделать, добавив например префикс:

```
public class A {
    private class B {}
    private String prefixMyFinalNameField;

    private B b = new B() {
        private void myMethod(String myFinalNameFields) {
            prefixMyFinalNameField = myFinalNameFields;
        }
    };
```

Есть ли возможность обратиться к приватному не статичному полю внешнего класса, что то вроде как **this** или **super**. Т.е. иметь абсолютно идентичные имена полей, но различать какая переменная к какому классу относится, точнее выполнить присвоение.

Comment: `Вопрос не несет практической значимости` — неправда, очень даже полезный вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, то к этой переменной вы можете обратиться следующим образом:

```
A.this.myFinalNameFields = myFinalNameFields;
```

Немного поясню:

```
class A {

    private class B {}

    private String myFinalNameFields;

    private B b = new B() {

        private String myFinalNameFields;

        private void myMethod(String myFinalNameFields) {
            A.this.myFinalNameFields = myFinalNameFields; //Присвоит значение полю класса A
            this.myFinalNameFields = myFinalNameFields; //Присвоит значение полю класса B
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Может я неправильно ставил вопрос, когда искал в гугле, т.е. я не нашел ответа. Но знал, что использование префикса это не единственный вариант. То что нужно!